# How to overlay Alpha masked image over finished Video without re-rendering the whole track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, graph-editor, movie-clip-editor

How can an alpha masked image (PNG with alpha) be overlayed over an already finished video footage?

I have a filmed (not rendered) Video footage with approx 40.000 Frames. Over the first 200 frames, there should be the mentioned overlay.

Everytime i do so, the whole video strip renders the wholel 40.000 Frames, even tough only the frist 200 were changed by adding the overlay.
Is there a way to change only the first 200 frames by adding the overlay, and then "stitch" it to the unchanged remaining 39.800 frames?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know is to split the video in two parts (200 frames and the rest), do the changes to the first part, render it, and than join the parts. 
BUT! To join parts without decoding the second one, you must render the first one with exactly the same parameters (codecs and so on). There are different programs for splitting and joining footage without decoding. It's not a problem to find one. But the main problem will be to adjust rendering parameters for the part that will be changed. Otherwise it will be decoded and than it all doesn't make any sense.

Comment: for splitting and joining I can recommend you My MP4Box app